# Error while refreshing a MS datawarehousing cube

Tags: sql-server-2005, data-warehouse, cubes

We have a cube that we are populating the data from the source tables. To get the data to reflect we are calling the "Analysis services processing task" component. While the cube is being refreshed we are getting the following error.

Description: OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Communication link failure; 08S01.  End Error  Error: 2009-03-13 02:26:11.24     Code: 0xC11F000C     Source: Process LedgerTransactions01 cube Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Item V', Name of 'dimItem' was being processed.

The cube is running in a SQL server environment and this issue is not happening always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/492f598f-d1c1-4598-bc23-c03fd5fcd96e) seems to suggest that one possible causes of this error is a lack of space on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that, but it didn't resolve the issue, however, we also found this answer, which did resolve the issue.

1. In BIDS (VS) Double click on DataSource
2. A window opens --> Go to Impersonation Information
3. Make sure that "Use the Service Account is selected.

[Original Post here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/fab54623-b40a-4974-8a28-b96e4e631738/)